# Identity with roots of $\frac{x}{x-p}+\frac{x}{x-q}+\frac{x}{x-r}+(x-s)=0$.

Tags: polynomials, roots

If the roots of $\frac{x}{x-p}+\frac{x}{x-q}+\frac{x}{x-r}+(x-s)=0$ are $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$, I want to show the identity:

$$ \frac{p^2}{(p-\alpha)(p-\beta)(p-\gamma)(p-\delta)}+\frac{q^2}{(q-\alpha)(q-\beta)(q-\gamma)(q-\delta)}+\frac{r^2}{(r-\alpha)(r-\beta)(r-\gamma)(r-\delta)}=0.$$

I am profoundly stuck on how to get the denominators to multiply and eliminate $s$. By the nature of $\alpha$ being a root I know that $\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-p}+\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-q}+\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-r}+(\alpha-s)=0$. I then wipe the denominators to get $\alpha(\alpha-q)(\alpha-r)+\alpha(\alpha-p)(\alpha-r)+\alpha(\alpha-p)(\alpha-q)+(\alpha-s)(\alpha-p)(\alpha-q)(\alpha-r)=0$. However this doesn't help at all because I am getting a product rotating between $p,q,r,s$ instead of $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$.

Could someone give me some leads on how to complete this question?

Comment: One may use the fact that $(x-p)(x-q)(x-r) \left( \frac{x}{x-p}+\frac{x}{x-q}+\frac{x}{x-r}+(x-s)\right)=$ $(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\gamma)(x-\delta)$, then $p(p-q)(p-r)=(p-\alpha)(p-\beta)(p-\gamma)(p-\delta)$ and so on.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Thank you! If possible, could you briefly explain any motivations for spotting that expression?

Comment: @Quippy The first is the fundamental theorem of algebra (which you used yourself), and the second is plugging in $p$. Farily natural things to try.

Comment: Standard form of such algebraic equation is polynomial form, then first step is making common denominator of left part which is $g(x)=(x-p)(x-q)(x-r)$, then numerator is $f(x)=$ $(x-p)(x-q)(x-r) \left( \frac{x}{x-p}+\frac{x}{x-q}+\frac{x}{x-r}+(x-s)\right)=$ $x(x-q)(x-r)+x(x-p)(x-r)+x(x-p)(x-q)+(x-p)(x-q)(x-r)(x-s)$. Then equation is $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$. All roots of this equation are roots of $f(x)=0$. $f(x)$ is polynomial of 4th degree, senior coefficient 1. $f(x)=0$ has at most 4 roots, then these roots are $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$, then $f(x)=(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\gamma)(x-\delta)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{x}{x-p}+\frac{x}{x-q}+\frac{x}{x-r}+(x-s)=0$$

Making common denominator gives

$$\frac{x(x-q)(x-r)+x(x-p)(x-r)+x(x-p)(x-q)+(x-p)(x-q)(x-r)(x-s)}{(x-p)(x-q)(x-r)}=0$$
Let numerator of LHS is $f(x)$ and denominator is $g(x)$.

All roots of $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$ are roots of $f(x)=0$, then $f(x)=0$ has at least four roots $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, $\delta$.
Note that $$f(x)=x(x-q)(x-r)+x(x-p)(x-r)+x(x-p)(x-q)+(x-p)(x-q)(x-r)(x-s)$$ is polynomial of 4th degree with senior coefficient $a_4=1$. Then it has at most 4 roots, and these roots are $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, $\delta$. Then $$f(x)=a_4(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\gamma)(x-\delta)$$

Then for any $x$ $$x(x-q)(x-r)+x(x-p)(x-r)+x(x-p)(x-q)+(x-p)(x-q)(x-r)(x-s)=\\=(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\gamma)(x-\delta)$$

Using this equality for $x=p$, $x=q$, $x=r$ gives

$$p(p-q)(p-r)=(p-\alpha)(p-\beta)(p-\gamma)(p-\delta)$$
$$q(q-p)(q-r)=(q-\alpha)(q-\beta)(q-\gamma)(q-\delta)$$
$$r(r-p)(r-q)=(r-\alpha)(r-\beta)(r-\gamma)(r-\delta)$$

Putting LHS of these equalities into identity which is necessary to prove instead of RHS expressions gives

$$\frac{p^2}{p(p-q)(p-r)}+\frac{q^2}{q(q-p)(q-r)}+\frac{r^2}{r(r-p)(r-q)}=0$$

Reducing and making common denominator gives

$$\frac{p(q-r)}{(p-q)(p-r)(q-r)}+\frac{-q(p-r)}{(p-q)(p-r)(q-r)}+\frac{r(p-q)}{(p-q)(p-r)(q-r)}=0$$

$$p(q-r)-q(p-r)+r(p-q)=0$$

$$pq-pr-pq-qr+pr-qr=0$$
$$0=0$$